# Estimate how well X-n values in a time series predict X

Tags: matlab, statistics, signal-processing

I'm trying to assess how well any given value **X** of a time-series **T** can be predicted or explained by the previous values of **X**, at variable lags **n**. For example, for what I need, at **n=3**, it is important to take into account **X-1**, **X-2** and **X-3** in the prediction of **X**.

In essence, I'm trying to understand how well my signal can be explained by the same signal at a given lag.

Is there any function in the matlab statistics toolbox to accomplish this? If not, how could I go about implementing this in matlab?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Primarily looks like a math or statistics question, not a programming question. I guess you are looking for autocorrelation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the suggestion. I'll check it out! Do you happen to know of any function that could achieve this? Specifically, by attributing different weights to the different lags?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of weights you want to set, don't recall any weights but I am also by no means an expert in this field.